# What is the R equivalent of Python function scipy.sparse.bmat?

Tags: python, r, sparse-matrix

Is there an R equivalent of Python's function [`scipy.sparse.bmat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.bmat.html)?

Comment: Not sure what you are using as matrix-class, but a simple search for ```R + block matrix``` gives some results.

Comment: Thanks, I using clss "dgCMatrix" returned by sparseMatrix function.

Answer (score 0):

A special solution specific for my code. 
The Python code looks like:

```
P = sparse.bmat([[None, W], [F, None]])
```

Where W and F are two sparse matrices.
The equivalent R code:

```
blk1 = Matrix::sparseMatrix(i=1,j=1,x=0,dims=c(nrow(W),ncol(F)))
blk2 = Matrix::sparseMatrix(i=1,j=1,x=0,dims=c(nrow(F),ncol(W)))
P=rbind(cbind(blk1,W),cbind(F,blk2))
```